# DrawText using FONT and SetBkMode in windows Dialog

Tags: c++, delphi, winapi, dialog

I'm creating a Dialog using [`CreateDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645434(v=vs.85).aspx).

in the dialog proc I do some drawing of text in `WM_PAINT`:

```
function DialogProc(hDlg: HWND; Msg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall;
...
case Msg of
  WM_PAINT:
    begin
      dc := BeginPaint(hDlg, ps);    
      bkmodePrev := SetBkMode(dc, TRANSPARENT);
      hfnt := SendMessage(hDlg, WM_GETFONT, 0, 0);
      hfntPrev := SelectObject(dc, hfnt);
      DrawTextW(dc, 'Text', -1, R, DT_SINGLELINE or DT_CENTER or DT_VCENTER);
      SelectObject(dc, hfntPrev);
      // SetBkMode(dc, bkmodePrev); // do I need this?
      EndPaint(hDlg, ps);
      Result := True;
    end;  
  end;
...
```

Now the question is, am I doing it right with the font, meaning that, is this the correct way to get the font handle of a dialog using `SendMessage(hDlg, WM_GETFONT, 0, 0)` and restoring it with `SelectObject(dc, hfntPrev`)?
Do I need to restore old BkMode of `bkmodePrev` using `SetBkMode(dc, bkmodePrev);`? or will `EndPaint` do that for me?

P.S: do I need to release the DC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Am I doing it right with the font?

Yes.

> Do I need to restore the old BkMode of bkmodeprev using `SetBkMode(dc, bkmodeprev)`, or will `EndPaint` do that for me?

`EndPaint` won't restore the background mix mode for you. But `EndPaint` does destroy the device context so it doesn't need to be restored. However, in my view, best practise is to restore the background mix mode whenever you change it. Then if you extend the code in the future you won't be surprised. But that's really a preference. You may take a different stance.

> Do I need to release the DC?

No, the call to `EndPaint` suffices.

---

I would write this like so:

```
dc := BeginPaint(hDlg, ps);    
bkmodeprev := SetBkMode(dc, TRANSPARENT);
hfnt := SendMessage(hDlg, WM_GETFONT, 0, 0);
hfntPrev := SelectObject(dc, hfnt);
DrawTextW(dc, 'Text', -1, R, DT_SINGLELINE or DT_CENTER or DT_VCENTER);
SelectObject(dc, hfntPrev);
SetBkMode(dc, bkmodeprev);
EndPaint(hDlg, ps);
```

Although, one might argue that it would be better to include some error checking.

---

As is pointed out in the comments you need to provide a return value for the `WM_PAINT` message. From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645469.aspx):

> If the dialog box procedure processes a message that requires a specific return value, the dialog box procedure should set the desired return value by calling SetWindowLong(hwndDlg, DWL_MSGRESULT, lResult) immediately before returning TRUE. Note that you must call SetWindowLong immediately before returning TRUE; doing so earlier may result in the DWL_MSGRESULT value being overwritten by a nested dialog box message.

Comment: EndPaint will destroy the device context causing the background mode to be defaulted (OPAQUE) for the next time round. There's no need to restore, only 'class' and 'private' DCs retain state.

Comment: Since he is processing `WM_PAINT`in a dialog box, he needs `SetWindowLongPtr( hDlg, DWLP_MSGRESYLT, (LONG_PTR)0 );` after `EndPaint` call. Only then he can return `TRUE` or maybe I have it wrong?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, So I don't need to restore `bkmodePrev`?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz, will the restoring of the `BkMode` have any bad effect? or should I simply ignore this and NOT restore it, leaving it up to the `EndPaint`?

Comment: @David, in this case, Should I call `SetWindowLongPtr( hDlg, DWLP_MSGRESYLT, (LONG_PTR)0 );` like AlwaysLearningNewStuff mentioned?

Comment: @kobik - No, I can't imagine any bad effect of restoring.